# Assembly - undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I am a newbie in assembly language, so I've got the following program (test.asm):

```
section .data
hello:     db 'Hello world!',10    
helloLen:  equ $-hello             

section .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax,4            
    mov ebx,1            
    mov ecx,hello        
    mov edx,helloLen     

    int 80h              

    mov eax,1            
    mov ebx,0            
    int 80h
```

I'm using NASM to assemble this program through the following command:

```
    nasm -f elf -o test.o test.asm
```

Then I'm using GCC to do the second stage through the following command (forgive me, I don't know what is the name of this stage):

```
    gcc -o test test.o
```

The following error appears in the CMD after running the last command:

> E:/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I know that the issue is related to the entry point , but my operating system is windows 10 64 bit.

Anyone have any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: You are using a Windows GCC tool chain and trying to compile a Linux program (can tell that because the `int 0x80` calls are Linux system calls). That won't work. So the question is, are you trying to create a Win64 program or a 64-bit Linux program?

Comment: Assembly is different for every architecture and operating system.  You can't just take a tutorial for i386 Linux and expect it to work on Windows.

Comment: @MichaelPetch i'am trying to create a Win64 program

Comment: To create a 64-bit program you'll have to make sure you are using a version of GCC that generates 64-bit code, you'll have to use `-f win64` instead of `-f elf` with NASM and you'll need to stop using `int 0x80` system calls and call Windows API directly. You should look for tutorial online specifically for creating Win64 programs with NASM. You can't use the Linux tutorials.